# Spotify Zoomed Out WIndow

Tags: 21.10, spotify, zooming

I'm using ubuntu 21.10 and I downloaded the SPotify from the software store. The window is really zoomed out, making it hard to read. Is there a way to adjust this or to zoom in more to make it easier to read?[image]

Comment: To make it easier to read, you can try a couple of things. First, you might want to attempt a zoom-in by pressing "Ctrl" and the "+" key simultaneously. This usually works for most applications and can make the text more readable. If that doesn't do the trick, you can explore your system display settings to see if there's an option to adjust the scaling or resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> will zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In my case, it can be solve by not using the fractional scaling. You can unable it in the settings>Screen Display>Fractional Scaling.
I don't know hot to solve it without removing it.